# How to use IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileName, OutputArray) in VB

Tags: vb.net

When using this code in VB I get the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.'

Can someone please give me the correct usage?

Full code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim OutputArray As New ArrayList
    Dim i = 0
    Dim Registrationdata 
    Dim FileName As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Output.txt"

    Private Sub IssueTicket_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IssueTicket.Click
        Dim Speed As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(Speedbox.Text(), Speed) Then
            If Speed <= 20 Or Speed > 300 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid speed between 20-200")
            ElseIf Registrationbox.Text() = Nothing Or Not Registrationbox.Text() Like "???? ???" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a vaild registration to continue e.g '1234 123'.")
            ElseIf Not IDBox.Text().StartsWith("9") Or Not IDBox.TextLength = 6 Or Not IsNumeric(IDBox.Text()) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid OfficerID starting with '9' and is 6 numbers long.")
            Else
                OutputArray.Add(Speed)
                OutputArray.Add(Registrationbox.Text())
                OutputArray.Add(IDBox.Text())
                MessageBox.Show("Ticket saved")
                i += 1
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveToFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToFile.Click
        Registrationbox.Text() = Registrationdata
        IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileName, OutputArray)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`. Use `List(Of String)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your problem quickly you could change your code to:

```
Dim OutputArray As New List(Of String)
...
OutputArray.Add(Speed.ToString())
OutputArray.Add(Registrationbox.Text())
OutputArray.Add(IDBox.Text())
```

Problem with your code is that `ArrayList` doesn't implement an IEnumerable interface, while `List` does and so `File.WriteAllText` works; but `List(Of String)` wants all the items to be of type string, so you have to convert your int to string before pushing it into the list.

Comment: `ArrayList` *does* implement `IEnumerable`.  The problem is that it doesn't implement `IEnumerable(Of String)`.  Using `List(Of String)` is certainly preferable, but I would think it would also be possible to use `Cast` on `ArrayList` to convert it from `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable(Of String)`.

Comment: @Lucas The way to thank a poster on Stack Overflow is to accept his answer. You do this by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.